# NestJs : inject property to an extended class and pass it to super()

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I'm trying to use NestJs and I'm facing an issue that should be easy to fix, but I can't find a clean solution.

Basicaly, I have an abstract class that needs a private connection property, set via the constructor properties.
I have another class that extends this abstract Class.

I have create a `database.module` that initiates the db connection as a provider. This provider is imported in the module(s).

When instantiating the Child class, I need to inject this db connection to the abstract class. And I can not find a propery way to do it. I found some bad solution (basically not using the @Inject functionnality) but this is not a clean way IMO/

Any help would be appreciate.

I tried many things (removing private key word in the Child Class but doesn't work)...

**Example of class I want to use**

```
abstract class AbstractClass<T extends Record<string, any>> {
  constructor(private readonly _dbConnection: string, value: T) {
    console.log(value);
  }

  showMeConnection(): string {
    return this._dbConnection;
  }
}

@Injectable()
class Child<T extends Record<string, any>> extends AbstractClass<T> { //<-- error here : Class 'Child<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'AbstractClass<T>'
  constructor(@Inject("DATASOURCE") readonly _dbConnection: string, value: T) { // <--- error here : _dbConnection not used
    super(_dbConnection, value);
  }
}

const t = new Child<number>(5); //<-- doens't work, need _dbConnection, but that shouldn't as it is a private injected proprty...
```

**database provider :**

```
const databaseProviders = [
  {
    provide: "DATASOURCE",
    useFactory: async (): Promise<string> => {
      const dataSource: string= await dbConnection();
      return dataSource;
    },
  },
];

export { databaseProviders };
```

**database module that I import in the Module of the class here above:**

```
@Module({
  providers: [...databaseProviders],
  exports: [...databaseProviders],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

Comment: Have you been able to find a proper solution for this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you want `_dbConnection` to be available to child classes and injected by Nest, first you need to not call `new` yourself, as that will stop all Dependency Injection for that instance and you'll be left managing everything. Next, you should move the `@Inject()` from the constructor to a property so that child classes can extend the original class and still let Nest handle the injection of the property (just don't use that property inside the constructor, use something like `onModuleInit()` instead).

Another option would be to make the `AbstractClass` a mixin instead, a function that takes in options and returns a reference to a class. You can view the [`AuthGuard`](https://github.com/nestjs/passport/blob/master/lib/auth.guard.ts) from `@nestjs/passport` for a good example of this.

Comment: thks willl look into this and get back with the most accurate solution

Answer (score 0):

So in the definition of your class

```
@Injectable()
class Child<T extends Record<string, any>> extends AbstractClass<T> {
  constructor(@Inject("DATASOURCE") readonly _dbConnection: string, value: T) {
    
  }
}
```

The constructor line is actually a shortcut for

```
@Injectable()
class Child<T extends Record<string, any>> extends AbstractClass<T> {
  private readonly _dbConnection: string;

  constructor(@Inject("DATASOURCE") _dbConnection: string, value: T) {
    this._dbConnection = _dbConnection;
  }
}
```

This means you just need to remove the `readonly` prefix for the constructor parameter to remove the auto-generation of the class variable. Then you will be able to use the `_dbConnection` parameter directly in the constructor.

If you also need to have access to `_dbConnection` outside of the constructor, you will need to manually declare the class variable

```
private readonly _dbConnection: string;
```

and affect it after the call to `super` with

```
this._dbConnection = _dbConnection;
```